# One hot encoding for sales prediction and kernel died

Tags: python, salesforce, one-hot-encoding, forecast

I am trying to forecast sales in daily basis and have a dataset 858935x15 features. Before feeding features to model, I want to make one hot encoding for categorical features. The product related features color, product_id, brand_id, category_id and subcategory_id are provided by int64 format and have below unique values;

------count of unique values -------

1. productid     -> 19359
2. color         -> 2243
3. categoryid    -> 101
4. brandid       -> 868
5. subcategoryid -> 103

If I made one-hot encode for these features, kernel is dying and the dataset becomes 17.5GB O.O

I guess, the problem is unique value count of product_id, do I strictly need to perform encoding for categorical features or can I leave them as they are especially for product_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can divide your question into two parts.

1. *How to prevent the kernel from dying.*

It dies when the storage limit is exceeded. It definitely does as you produce almost 20000 new columns. Based on my humble experience I can say one-hot encoding will be a very rude technique for the features `color` and `brandid` as well, as 1000 new features blows out your data significantly. I suggest you using algorithms, which can perfectly deal with categorical features: **tree-based** algorithms, such as **Random Forest** (please refer [sklearn implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)) or **Gradient Boosting methods**.
(please refer [LightGBM library](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

2. *Other ways to deal with categorical features.*

If you insist on using linear or neural-based models, there is an amazing technique called **mean encoding**. You group the observations by each unique value of the feature and substitute the feature values with the mean values of target variable for each group. This technique does lose some information, containing in the feature, however, it does not require the swell of your dataset. [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-try-mean-encoding-17057262cd0) explains the profits of using this approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks. All my categorical variables are stored as integer btw. So that meand can I directly use Random Forest, right? Because as I know, random forest only accept numerical features. In that case, should I perform scaling to that numerical categorical features?

Comment: 1. You can use *Random Forest* straightaway, that is right. In case you need to deal with categorical values, which are **not** stored as integers, you may consider using `LightGBM` or `Catboost`, which deal with them on their own. 2. You do not need scaling, as any tree-based model creates `M` folds (a hyperparameter, the default value usually equals 256) of values, where all values in each fold are treated equally. Therefore, you do not need the scaling procedure for tree-based methods.

Comment: Can I also ask another question? I do not scale any numerical categorical features for tree based algorithms so it means I dont need to perform scaling for numerical features also like prices? However, if I want to use nn based models I should perform encoding for numerical categoricals and numerical features.

Comment: That is true, you do not need to scale **any** features, used in tree-based algorithms. However, in your case features `productid`, `colorid` and `brandid` have great number of unique values, thus, some values will come upon the same fold and hence get the same value from the tree's point of view. Thereby you should thoroughly produce label encoding since similar values should be encoded with similar numbers. As for NNs, standartization (scaling) should be beneficial, however, it should not be produced for one-hot features.